# In PhpStorm, is there a way to unsplit the terminal?

Tags: terminal, phpstorm

In PhpStorm, I like to split my terminal, but I can't figure out how to close split terminals. In VSCode, there is the 'kill terminal' menu option, but I don't see a similar option in PhpStorm.

I am making new terminals with `right click > Split Right`

I tried right clicking the unwanted terminal window as well as looking in the `View` menu, to no avail. There doesn't appear to be a keybinding for this functionality either, so I'm thinking it may not be supported.

*The context menu that comes up when I right click on an unwanted terminal (no "unsplit" or "kill terminal" option):*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just focus the unwanted terminal and use `Close Tab` action on it (from your screenshot).

That closes the split for me while keeping all other split terminals intact (tried on Windows 10, PhpStorm 2023.2.3, `cmd.exe` as a shell)

[image]

Comment: tried on linux and it does work aswell

Comment: Thank you! I guess I had only tried using the "close tab" option when right clicking on the tabs at the top... facepalm